# Do meat grinders need to have cutting blade

Tags: meat, grinding

I got a Game Winner meat grinder #8, but it did not come with cutting blade. Do you need this to grind meat?

Comment: Can you post a picture of your grinder and (if possible) of the piece you know it's missing. My instinct is to say yes, you do need the cutting blade to grind the meat.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the relevent description on a [site](http://www.academy.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10151_10051_388603_-1) selling that particular meat grinder:

> The Game Winner™ Hunting Gear #8 Grinder grinds up to 4 lb. of meat per minute and features a powder-coated cast aluminum body, **3, 4.5, and 7 mm stainless-steel cutting plates and a stainless-steel cutting blade*** for durability. The Cam-Lock locking mechanism and thermal reset button offer safe operation, while the feet-forward design helps prevent tipping. Full-power grind, reverse and off modes. 400-watt motor.
>
> ***Features and Benefits*** •stainless-steel cutting plates and cutting blade for durability

It definitely looks like you'll need the cutting blade and cutting plates.